# Getting 404 error when making a request from Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i have created a war file and kept it inside webapps directory in tomcat and starting the tomcat but when i am hitting **http://localhost:8181/HelloWeb/hello** i am getting 404 error. i am new to spring mvc any help will be appreciated. Below are my files (doing the example given in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm.

HelloController.java

```
package dummyPackageOne;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {



@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String printHello(ModelMap modelMap){

    modelMap.addAttribute("message", "this is the message");
    return "hello";
    }
}
```

this is my hello.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloWeb-Servlet.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="dummyPackageOne" />
  <bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

  </beans>
```

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>springTest</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Comment: What is the name of your .war file? Is it HelloWeb.war, ROOT.war or something else?

Comment: Also, can you see that your .war file is being unpacked by Tomcat (also in the webapp folder)?

Comment: springTest.war and it is unpacked with name springTest. and in WEB-INF folder i have HelloWeb-servlet.xml, web.xml, classes/HelloController.java , jsp/ hello.jsp, lib/*jars(all jar files) .

Comment: checked with war name HelloWeb.war . but same issue.

Comment: tomcat runs on 8181?

Comment: Sorry folks, i was running http-apr and ajp-apr on the same port that's why getting the problem . changed it to different ports now it is working fine.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<mvc:annotation-driven>`  after your `<context:component-scan base-package="dummyPackageOne" />`. This is required to register HandlerMapping and HandlerAdapter.

Also make sure your war/exploded war name matches your web context.